# INNER JOIN or STRAIGHT_JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

> | users_transactions | 
>       CREATE TABLE `users_transactions` (
>         `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>         `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>         UNIQUE KEY `user_id_transaction_id_unique` (`user_id`,`transaction_id`)
>       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
>
> | transactions | 
>         CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
>         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>         `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>         `transaction_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>         PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>         KEY `index_transactions_on_transaction_date` (`transaction_date`)
>       ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

I tried to run this SQL

```
SELECT `transactions`.`id`, `transactions`.`transaction_date` 
FROM `transactions` 
INNER JOIN `users_transactions` 
ON `transactions`.`id` = `users_transactions`.`transaction_id` 
WHERE `users_transactions`.`user_id` = 71720 
ORDER BY `transactions`.`transaction_date` DESC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

User 71720 has more than 27000 transactions, this SQL will cost > 4s. I tried to explain it, and it showed

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************

id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE   
table: users_transactions   
type: ref possible_keys: user_id_transaction_id_unique    
key: user_id_transaction_id_unique   
key_len: 4  
ref: const    
rows: 52968  <--- It returns too many rows, bad smell 
Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using file sort

*************************** 2. row ***************************

id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE   
table: transactions    
type: eq_ref possible_keys: PRIMARY    
key: PRIMARY   
key_len: 8    
ref: NULL   
rows: 1    
Extra: Using where 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

which shows it didn't use `index_transactions_on_transaction_date`.

While I tried to use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, it was using `index_transactions_on_transaction_date`, and was executed quickly on User 71720. But for other users who don't have many transactions, `STRAIGHT_JOIN` is much slower than `INNER JOIN`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.transaction_date
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     users_transactions ut
     ON t.id = ut.transaction_id
WHERE ut.user_id = 71720
ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

You have a problem where you have two different execution plans, and one works best for some data and one works best for others.  I don't think MySQL does a good job handling this.

Is there any way that you can put a `transaction_date` column into `user_transactions`?  That would give you the ability to optimize the query for both cases.

I would suggest rewriting it as:

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand `different execution plans`. Why there is difference between big data and small data? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Prajna . . . If I understand correctly, there isn't a difference and that is the problem.  You want there to be a difference, because one plan works better on some data than others.

Answer (score 0):

try below query-

```
SELECT t.id, t.transaction_date
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     users_transactions ut
     ON t.id = ut.transaction_id
WHERE ut.user_id = 71720 
and t.transaction_date >= subdate(curdate(),interval 30 day) 
ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Note: Assuming this user have at least 25 records in last 30 days or you can increase this window...

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Both `INNER JOIN` and `STRAIGHT_JOIN` will eventually use `index_transactions_on_transaction_date `, separate indices only appear in `possible keys`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: index on date will not be beneficial for you as you are not filtering any data based on date....here best way will be that put a condition on date as you are just trying to get latest 25 records..check updated query in my answer...

Comment: Seems to me it's almost the same ;(